# How to send HTTP requests to specific port using Ciao?

Tags: http, arduino-uno-wifi-dev-ed

I currently have a working REST client on my Arduino, but the requests always go to port 80. How do I make it send the request to a specific port?

This is my current code:

```cpp
/*
File: RestClient.ino
This example makes an HTTP request after 10 seconds and shows the result both in
serial monitor and in the wifi console of the Arduino Uno WiFi.

Note: works only with Arduino Uno WiFi Developer Edition.

http://www.arduino.org/learning/tutorials/boards-tutorials/restserver-and-restclient
*/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <UnoWiFiDevEd.h>
    
void setup() {
  const char* connector = "rest";
  const char* server = "download.arduino.org";
  const char* method = "GET";
  const char* resource = "/latest.txt";

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ciao.begin();
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  delay(10000);
  doRequest(connector, server, resource, method);
}
    
void loop() {
}
    
void doRequest(const char* conn, const char* server, const char* command, const char* method) {
  CiaoData data = Ciao.write(conn, server, command, method);
  if (!data.isEmpty()) {
    Ciao.println( "State: " + String (data.get(1)) );
    Ciao.println( "Response: " + String (data.get(2)) );
    Serial.println( "State: " + String (data.get(1)) );
    Serial.println( "Response: " + String (data.get(2)) );
  } else {
    Ciao.println ("Write Error");
    Serial.println ("Write Error");
  }
}
```

If I add for example `:8080` to the end of the `server` variable, it does not work.

How do I make that request go to a specific port?

Comment: Chances are you can't unless 'Ciao' allows you to.  Have a look a PAT, port forwarding or proxy servers.  Depending on you topology one of those may be able to help.

Comment: change the firmware to WiFi Link https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1#uno-wifi-with-wifi-link-firmware

Comment: update 2022. put AT firmware 1.7.5 into the esp8266 and use my WiFiEspAT library

Answer (score 0):

You can find a port definition for your Arduino in this path:

/usr/lib/python2.7/ciao/connectors/restserver/restserver.json.conf

```
{
 "name" : "restserver",
 "description" : "REST server connector for the Ciao Core",
 "authors": ["Arduino Team <swdev@arduino.org>;"],
 "repository" : "https://github.com/arduino-org/Ciao",
 "version" : "0.0.2",
 "params" : {
            "port" : 80
             },
 "log" : {
         "level" : "info"
         }
}
```

The confusing part is that your Arduino has a server-client connection to itself from the CPU/Linino server to the MCU/Arduino client.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CiaoRestServer

Comment: OP has Uno WiFi, not Yun. The library UnoWiFiDevEd has a ciao-like object but the WiFi is served by esp8266